# I don't have module launcher tag in Acceleo in Eclipse

Tags: acceleo

I am using Eclipse version 3.6.2, and I have installed Acceleo plugin for it but according to the instructions and tutorials I have read, I should be having module launcher under Acceleo tag in 'New' menu but I don't have it. I tried to install the modules from module update link in acceleo, however during the installing the modules an error occurs showing this message

*Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: UML 2.1 to Java generator 1.0.0.201102031027 (org.acceleo.module.pim.uml21.gen.java_feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201102031027)
  Missing requirement: UML 2.1 to Java generator 1.0.0.201102031027 (org.acceleo.module.pim.uml21.gen.java_feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201102031027) requires 'fr.obeo.acceleo.gen 0.0.0' but it could not be found*

Can anyone please tell me, why I am getting this error or why I don't have module launcher?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have installed the latest version of Acceleo that has been release last month, Acceleo 3.1 if that's not the case, you can install it with the Acceleo 3.1.x update site: http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/acceleo/updates/releases/3.1

You can find the Acceleo wizards under the new menu only if you are using the Acceleo perspective (Window -> Open perspective -> Other) otherwise you have to use the regular menu for all wizards (File -> New -> Other).

The Acceleo generator that you are installing is the UML to Java module for Acceleo 2.x. Acceleo 2.x and Acceleo 3.x are not compatible and therefore you cannot install this module unless you install the old version of Acceleo (its plugin are named fr.obeo.acceleo.* instead of org.eclipse.acceleo.*).

But, this generator is currently being migrated to Acceleo 3.1 and if you need it, you can grab it quite easily. This generator is licenced under the open source licence named EPL and its source code is available on github.com. If you want to install it, go to [Github.com](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Java-Generation) and download the source code (by using git, or the download button) then go in the root folder (the one visible in the link with the "plugins", "tests" subfolders) and then you can use maven 3 (maven 2 is not enough to build an Acceleo generator) to build the generator by typing "**mvn clean package**".

Maven will download half of the internet the first time you'll try to build it and in the end you will have an update site for this module in the "rootfolder/updatesite/org.obeonetwork.pim.uml2.gen.java.updatesite/target/repository" folder. You just have to install this UML to Java generator by adding this as an "local" update site. Once it's done, you can restart your Eclipse and then a new menu named "Acceleo model to text" will be available once you right click on a *.uml file in your workspace. With this menu, you'll be able to generate Java from this uml model.

The uml model in question need to have been created with a project compatible with EMF like the uml project of the Eclipse foundation (org.eclipse.uml.uml2). You can find an example of UML model in the Acceleo 3 examples (File -> New -> Examples).

If you don't need to build the generator, you can simply use its source code after having download it from github. You can use it, test it, fork it or even contribute to it as you want. And if you find a bug in this generator, you can report the problem on the [Acceleo forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/24/) in the Eclipse Foundation (please use an [acceleo] tag in your title on the Eclipse forum) or on stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stephane, I installed acceleo 2 built in eclipse Ganymede and now I have Module launcher :))) ... Thank you again.

Comment: Hi Daniel, i think it is a good idea your comment to post as a answer and check as a solution. So this question will be marked as finished.